# Replacing " with pretty quotes on a lot of files

Tags: text-processing

I have a lot of UTF-8 encoded files with words quoted like this

```
"word"
```

and I want to replace the quotes with

```
“word”   (the first quotes are upside down and the second is normal)
```

Because the beginning quote has to be replaced by a different quote compared to the second, I don’t have a clue on how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all quotes are around word characters (letter, digit or underscore) and separated by non-word characters then with gnu `sed` you can write:

```
sed -i 's/"\(\w*\)"/“\1”/g' *.txt
```

I've added `-i` option to replace in place all `*.txt` files in current directory (due to `-i` option please make a backup before run).

Comment: when I try the command I receive this error **sed: 1: “file1.txt": invalid command code e**  strangely there is a smart quote on the error message...

Comment: Is `file1.txt` one of the files which you want to change? What is its content? Also are you using gnu `sed` (check with `sed --version`)?

Comment: sorry about that, was an error on the file. THANKS!!!!